# Highcharts mouse tracking behaviour with multiple arearange & line series

Tags: javascript, highcharts, mouseover

I have created a chart that uses `arearange` series as a kind of gantt overlay against a `line` series.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zvj079xj/1/)

The problem is that when hovering over the `arearange` series, the tooltip jumps down to the other series as you move the cursor from left to right.  The image below shows this effect (the red dot denotes mouse position):

[image: jumpy tooltip]

I have tried setting the following options as described in the [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.stickyTracking) :

```
plotOptions.series.stickyTracking: false
tooltip.shared: false
```

And I have even tried: `tooltip.snap: 0`

But the jumping effect still occurs.  My intention is to plug into the `mouseOver` and `mouseOut` events so that I can display some additional details below the chart - this however is not feasible with the current behaviour.

Is it possible to have the `mouseOver` & `mouseOut` events fired only when the cursor moves directly over the series?  Is this down to my configuration or a limitation with the current highcharts version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking [this](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5315) suggestion from the Highcharts GitHub page, I have interpolated some extra points into my area range so that the tooltip can find the closest point (as opposed to the line which I was expecting).

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7czk7nvu/6/) for an example.

`arearange` interpolation function:

```
function interpolateAreaRange(data, splitBy) {
  var interpolate = function(x1, x2, x3, y1, y2) {
    return y1 + (y2 - y1) * (x2 - x1) / (x3 - x1);
  };
  var newData = [],
    step = 0,
    xStart = 0,
    xEnd = 0,
    xNew = 0,
    p = 0;
  if (data.length > 1 && splitBy > 0) {
    newData.push(data[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
      p = i - 1;
      xStart = data[p][0];
      xEnd = data[i][0];
      step = (xEnd - xStart) / splitBy;

      for (var s = 1; s <= splitBy; s++) {
        xNew = xStart + (step * s);
        newData.push([
          xNew,
          interpolate(xStart, xNew, xEnd, data[p][1], data[i][1]),
          interpolate(xStart, xNew, xEnd, data[p][2], data[i][2])
        ]);
      }
      newData.push(data[i]);
    }
    return newData;
  }
  return data;
}
```